# How to specify entire directory contents as dependencies in dojo custom build?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using custom build of dojo as specified here http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/custom-builds.html

profile file (say sample.profile.js) is something like -

```
dependencies ={

  layers:  [
      {
      name: "mydojo.js",
      dependencies: [
          "dijit.Button",
          "dojox.wire.Wire",
          "dojox.wire.XmlWire",
          "explosive.space.Modulator"
      ]
      }
  ],

  prefixes: [
      [ "dijit", "../dijit" ],
      [ "dojox", "../dojox" ],
      [ "explosive", "../../explosive" ]
  ]

};
```

Now I want to add all the files in `explosive/space` as dependencies. How can I do this apart from running a script which lists all the files and adds them in this profile file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no wildcard option. If you are doing a build properly, it shouldn’t matter, since dependency resolution will find all of the modules that your application is actually using so long as you provide a reference to the entrypoint module in your build profile.

Comment: I actually experimented with wildcard - like `explosive.space.*`. But am running into *dependency missing* errors. What if there are multiple modules which don't depend on any other module. How to specify in such case?